# Is the full browser window a html document?

Tags: browser, window, document

So I am Curious about how the browser window itself is generated and what it is.

I don't mean the website itself, I mean the Ctrl + f components , the tabs, the x mark to close the browser , the url input field, the history buttons etc.

How are they programmed , rendered and what is listening to the events?

Are these html elements as well?

Answer (score 0):

The actual browser would be made in another language like c++ or rust, html is only used to create webpages.

Comment: Thanks, and the elements outside of the webpage, they can never be accessed by Js?

Comment: Not that I am aware of